# How to use "isOriginLeft" in jQuery Masonry?

Tags: jquery, wordpress, themes

I'm using a wordpress theme that uses jQuery Masonry to restack the post thumbnails when the browser is resized. However, I need them to stack from the right rather than the left. I found this ["isOriginLeft": false](http://masonry.desandro.com/options.html#isoriginleft) option on the Masonry site, but can't seem to get it to work.

Any suggestion? ANY help would be appreciated, jQuery is not my forte.

The site can be found here: http://brittonhack.com/new/

Here's the functions.js code:

```
// masonry code 
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#post-area').masonry({
    // options
    itemSelector : '.post',
    isOriginLeft: false,
    // options...
  isAnimated: true,
  animationOptions: {
    duration: 400,
    easing: 'linear',
    queue: false
  }

  });
});


// hover code for index  templates
$(document).ready(function() {

        $('#post-area .image').hover(
            function() {
                $(this).stop().fadeTo(300, 0.8);
            },
            function() {
                $(this).fadeTo(300, 1.0);
            }
        );  


});


// comment form values
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#comment-form input").focus(function () {
        var origval = $(this).val();    
        $(this).val("");    
        //console.log(origval);
        $("#comment-form input").blur(function () {
            if($(this).val().length === 0 ) {
                $(this).val(origval);   
                origval = null;
            }else{
                origval = null;
            };  
        });
    });
});


// clear text area
$('textarea.comment-input').focus(function() {
   $(this).val('');
});

var container = document.querySelector('#post-area');
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $container.masonry({
    "isOriginLeft": false,
    "isOriginTop": true
  });
});
```